# Creating permalinks with Express/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, permalinks

Suppose I have the following schemas for a LMS app:

```
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    code: { type: String, required: true, unique: 1, uppercase: 1 }, // ex. CSCA48
    quizzes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Quiz' }]
});

const QuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }, // ex. 1a
    questions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }]
});

const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: String, required: true }, // ex. 4
    question: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String },
    choices: [String],
    answers: [String]
});
```

I built (or tried to build) the app following RESTful API guidelines. For example,

```
GET /courses/[ObjectID]
GET /courses/[ObjectID]/quizzes
GET /courses/[ObjectID]/quizzes/[ObjectID]
GET /courses/[ObjectID]/quizzes/[ObjectID]/questions
```

The reason why I used ObjectID was because they are unique and makes it easy to retrieve objects -- particularly with [app.param()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param). For example,

```
router.param('courseID', controllers.Course.getCourseByParam);
router.param('quizID', controllers.Quiz.getQuizByParam);
router.param('questionID', controllers.Question.getQuestionByParam);

router.get('/courses', controllers.Course.getCourses);
router.get('/courses/:courseID', controllers.Course.getCourse);
router.get('/courses/:courseID/quizzes', controllers.Quiz.getQuizzes);
router.get('/courses/:courseID/quizzes/:quizID/questions', controllers.Question.getQuestions);
```

But now, I am wondering if there is a way to not use ObjectID in order make the URLs more friendly/readable?

```
GET /courses/[code]/quizzes/[name]/questions/[number] 

ex. /courses/CSCA48/quizzes/1a/questions/4
```

My biggest concern with this is that, although course `code` is unique, quiz `name` and question `number` are not. For example, `/courses/CSCA48/quizzes/1b/questions/4` would be a different question for a different quiz. So, unless I am mistaken, it is not really possible to use `app.param()`. Therefore I would need to somehow ensure that the quiz belongs to the matched course and then question belongs to the matched quiz.

I am not really looking for code, just a general idea of how I can approach this (or not).

Comment: Is the combination `[code]-[name]-[number]` unique?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, it would be.

Comment: They may be a unique combination, but if retrieving the result is going to rely on using "populated paths" ( which is essentially at least another two queries to MongoDB in addition to any basic request ) then it is simply a really bad idea and you should re-think the design.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't quite understand. In my original design, the number of queries would always be minimum the number of parameters. For example, `/courses/[ObjectID]/quizzes/[ObjectID]` is at least 2 queries -- which would be the same if I did `/courses/[code]/quizzes/[name]`.

Comment: No it would not be the same. If you look at what you were provided for an answer, it uses `.populate()` with a `match` option to query the `name` ( for example ) as opposed to the `ObjectId` that is the only thing actually present in the `Course` model itself. And then similarly  the `number` within the then "joined" detail from `Quiz`  to match on the `Question`. This now becomes **three** queries as opposed to **one**, which is optimal. You need to turn on debugging `mongoose.set('debug', true)` and the the actual queries being issued.

Comment: Point is you should try to avoid issuing "joins" just to match criteria. And in fact `.populate()` is somewhat "old hat". MongoDB can do `$lookup` now, which is more effective since it actually happens on the server. But nonetheless, you should be modelling to retrieve the information you actually need with a **single** request. Which generally means being able to retrieve from **one** collection, and not rely on "simulations of joins" nor really "any joins that can be avoided", by better modelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the combination `[code]-[name]-[number]` is unique (and `[code]` too, which is important), you should be able to run a query that would bring up the correct question:

```
Course.findOne({ code : req.params.code })
      .populate({
        path     : 'quizzes',
        match    : { name : req.params.name },
        populate : {
          path  : 'questions',
          match : { number : req.params.number }
        }
      })
```

Alternatively, you could add two fields to `QuestionSchema` to reflect both the course and the quiz to which the question belongs, in which case you'd only have to run a single query to find the correct question document (population requires 3 queries).

Comment: Interesting first solution. I'm assuming this only works up to 2 nested levels? For example, `[code]-[name]-[number]-[anothervar]` would require doing your second solution?

Comment: @Mikey if you add a populated field to `QuestionSchema` (which you would then query using `req.params.anothervar`) you should be able to go a level deeper.

Comment: I like this. I'll try it out later and let you know.